# jquery searchabledropdown in form fails to get $_POST or $_GET values

Tags: php, jquery, forms, submit

I am unable to get the php POST variables for my select field anytime I try to use the jquery searchabledropdown plugin.  If I comment out the jquery, I can get the POST form data just fine.  However if I add the drop down (which pulls data from the database and assigns the value to the select from, the $_POST variable comes back blank.  This happens across all browsers for every instance that uses the plugin and the drop down.  I have searched this forum for the last week and tried assigning a hidden value and all other similar solutions to no success.  Can a jquery guru provide some assistance?

editclass.php

```
<script src='/app/js/spectrum.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='/app/css/spectrum.css' />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/js/jquery.searchabledropdown-1.0.8.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#grade").searchable();
});
</script>

<?php
$sql="select value,type_id from type where category='grade' and active_flg=1 order by value";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$gradevalues="<option value=0>Search:</option>";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    if($teacherid1==$row['person_id']){$selected1="selected";}else{$selected1="";}
    $grade=$row['value'];
    $typeid=$row['type_id'];
    $gradevalues.='<option '.$selected1.' value="'.$typeid.'">'.$grade.'</option>';
}?>

  <form action="/app/forms/editclass_post.php"  method="POST" >
     <select name="grade" id="grade">
          <?php echo $gradevalues;?>
        </select>
<input type="submit" name="submit"  value="Update Class" class="button">
</form>


editclass_post.php

<?php

echo $_POST['grade'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you also be including jquery, e.g:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script><br />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/js/jquery.searchabledropdown-1.0.8.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Oh by the way it doesn't seem like the jquery searchabledropdown plays nicely with jquery-1.9.1 so you might have to use jquery-1.8.3.